How to find the vertical component of impact velocity when projectile hits the ground (See question below)
A ball of mass 0.1kg is thrown from a height of 1m above ground level towards the ground with an initial velocity of 8m/s at an angle 30$^{o}\ $to the horizontal. The ball experiences the effect of gravity (g=10m/s$^{2}\ $) and a resistance force numerically equal to one thousandth of the square of its velocity in both the horizontal and vertical directions.
You are given the time taken for the particle to reach maximum height is 0.4s and the maximum height is 1.8m.
a) Find the vertical component of the impact velocity
b) Hence, find the total time of flight of the ball
Answers: a) 6m/s, b) 1s
So far, I have integrated the $\ddot{y}$ with respect to t to find $\dot{y}$ and y. I have assumed that vertically upwards and right is positive, and taken origin as the point of launch.
$\dot{y} = \frac{10 \sqrt{10} \left( e^{\frac{\sqrt{10} t}{5}} - 1 \right)}{1 + e^{\frac{\sqrt{10} t}{5}}}$
$y = 10\sqrt{10} \left( t-2 \ln \left( e^{\frac{-20}{\sqrt{10}} t} + 1 \right) \right) + 1.8 - 10\sqrt{10}$
From here, I am not sure how to solve for t when y = -1 since one t is outside and one t is inside the ln expression. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I'm not convinced. the shown values for time to climax and its height are obviously calculated without drag impact. What could this numbers help?

You also didn't account for the fact that drag depends on the magnitude of velocity, so the $x$-component matters too. You should have a system of coupled nonlinear ODEs. You may have to solve it numerically.
